# disabling javascript on HTML print page

Tags: javascript, html, printing

Is there a way to disable javascript when a page is printed?

I have created print specific stylesheets, but when I print preview the javascript is still interacting with some elements (such as cascades which hide portions of content etc).

When its being printed I would like ALL javascript disabled. Is this even possible?

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense.  When a print preview is rendered, it should be static and any JavaScript has already executed.   There's no "still interacting" going on.  The only thing you can do is use events to "undo" anything JavaScript has done.  The best approach would be only switching classes with JavaScript (instead of setting styles directly on the element) and then styling those classes specifically for print.

Answer (score 1):

**after edit**

you can use

`window.onbeforeprint = function() { }`

and

`window.onafterprint = function() { }`

ook on webkit this should works

```
var mediaQuery = window.matchMedia('print');
mediaQuery.addListener(function(mql) {
    if(mql.matches) {
        console.log('before print');
    }
    else {
        console.log('after print');
    }
});
```

Comment: Not supported in Chrome/Safari/Opera.

Comment: When Chrome renders its print preview it will switch the media to print and then back to normal after rendering is complete.  This is probably a good enough opportunity to "undo" any changes that JavaScript has done, but for best compatibility the right approach is to have your print styles override anything that JavaScript does.